# How to render a hyperlink within a string from a variable in Pug without unescaping the rest of the text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping, pug

Imagine your user writes a post and includes a hyperlink or two somewhere within the text. The whole thing is saved as a string in the database. To render the content and make the links clickable, one would do the following:

```
const urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
let content = userInput = "Hey everybody, look at this cool site I found: http://www.cool-site.com"
let url = content.match(urlRegex);
.postContents !{content.replace(url[0], `<a href="${url[0]}">${url[0]}</a>`)}
```

The marker !{ } makes sure that Pug treats html tags as what they are. However, this approach is not practical. A malicious user could easily post `<a href="www.u-r-hacked.com">Click me!</a>` and Pug would take this string and render it because the content is being unescaped. If I escape the content, on the other hand, the recursively added tag `<a href="blahblah">blahblah</a>` will be treated as text and no links will be clickable. One solution I thought about is to decompose the whole string into an array of words to later recompose it again using #{ } for non-urls and !{ } for urls, although it seems rather complicated for a problem many other developers might have encountered already.

Note: I know the code is not looping through all the matched urls. I will figure that out later. My problem now is to find a way to "urlify" the text in a safe way.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the links to render as clickable, or do you want to remove the links from user input text?

Comment: The idea is to make them clickable. For example, the usual approach is to transform www.stackoverflow.com into <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>. But unescaping the content in Pug (they call it interpolation) would allow users to create their own tags by typing the appropriate instructions in html.

Comment: Gotcha. You want users to input urls as strings, not anchor tags. And then you want to be able to transform that url string into a real link with Pug. But you don't want to use unescaped interpolation.

Comment: Modifying your question to include a sample input and sample desired output string would be helpful for others attempting to help.

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Express or Gulp?

Comment: I'm using Express, if that helps. And the user would input something like this: "Hey everyone, I found a cool link I want to share.Check it out: ```http://www.cool-link.com```". So the link is received and stored as text. But, when rendering the user's post, I want the link to be an actual clickable link, not just text. Like this: "Hey everyone, I blah blah. Check it out: ```<a href="http://www.cool-link.com">```http://www.cool-link.com```<a/>"

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage an existing package like [`linkify-urls`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/linkify-urls), and pass that through to Pug to be able to use during compilation:

```js
const linkifyUrls = require('linkify-urls');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { linkifyUrls });
});
```

```
.postContents!= linkifyUrls(userInput)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Sean. Your answer helped me solve the problem. Although the package you suggested is mostly used to convert strings into links, I did manage to find a package that removes html tags. Its name is pretty self-explanatory: sanitize-html.

Comment: @David Your question centered around turning strings into links.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The question was about converting urls into links from user input without rendering user-typed html. The best approach I found is to use a sanitization package to remove any user-generated html and then convert the remaining urls into links.